# Problem with relation @ManyToOne in Spring Boot, Hibernate, JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have classes -> Country and City.

1. I wanna create works request, that when I call to get all countries, I will get all countries, with cities.
2. When I call to get all cities, I will get all cities with only countries from Country model.
3. I wanna add new cities with relation to countries.

My Country model class:

```
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private Long id;

@NotEmpty(message = "Name of country is mandatory.")
@Column(unique = true)
private String nameOfCountry;

@NotBlank(message = "Name of capital is mandatory.")
private String capital;

@Max(value = 17098242L, message = "Maximum value for population = 10000000000")
private Long surface;

private String countryCode;

private String telephoneCode;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "country_Id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private List<CityModelDao> cityModelDao;
```

My City model class:

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private Long id;

@NotEmpty(message = "Name of country is mandatory.")
@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String nameOfCity;
```

I know that I don't have here @ManyToOne, but I still do it wrong and now I haven't got more ideas.

My response from get countries:
[image]

And this is it what i want.

But when i call to get cities my response is:
[image]

Unfortunately I havent got information about country.

In db I have in cities information about fk from country:
[image]

Could you help me to do works relation? I ve tried something like:

CityModel:

```
    @ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "country_Id")
private CountryModelDao countryId;
```

CountryModel:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "countryId", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<CityModelDao> cityModelDao;
```

But it was wrong. And when I tried with above relation city, I got error.

Could You tell me how to do correct @ManyToOne in this case? What I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simplistic bi-directional OneToMany relationship model should be:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "countryId")
private List<CityModelDao> cityModelDao;
```

You set Country as the owner of the relationship Country - City;
You expect an attribute 'countryId' in the CityModelDao;

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
private CountryModelDao countryId;
```

You will populate with data based on a join operation that will be executed on the column country_id from the CityModelDao table.

Of course, afterwards, you can enrich the annotations with orphan removal, cascade type etc.

**LE:**
You are using this via REST and you need to avoid the infinite loop.

Please update the relations to:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "countryId")
private List<CityModelDao> cityModelDao;
```

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
private CountryModelDao countryId;
```

Comment: I add response for your code above, because it was too long to add it in comment.

Comment: I updated my answer so you can avoid the infinite loop.